# Calculating Forces using equations of equilibrium

Tags: stresses

The homogeneous bar shown in Fig. P-106 is supported by a smooth pin at C and a cable that runs from A to B around the smooth peg at D. Find the stress in the cable if its diameter is 0.6 inch and the bar weighs 6000 lb.

[image]

When using the equilibrium of moment equation at point C, The Tension in the string is found to be 2957.13 lb.

```
6000(5) = 5(T) + 10(T)*(3/(34)^(1/2))
```

I tried to use the equation of equilibrium for Vertical Forces.

```
  6000 = T + T(3/(34)^(1/2))

  T = 3961.714 lb
```

[image]

Is there any mistake in applying the equilibrium vertical condition? I'm having trouble finding any faults. The diagram for forces is given below

Comment: Could you show us the Forces that you have used for your calculation result ? Applied at which point, and their names, the effect in question ?

Comment: You forget the reaction at point 'C'. You have a vertical reaction there, but no moment or reaction torque because it's a smooth pin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track but as noted by commenter Sam, the free body diagram for beam AC should include the support reactions from the pin at point C.

[image: Free Body Diagram of Beam AC]

Then, the general procedure using the equations of equilibrium will be:

1. Sum moments about point C to solve for cable tension T
   $$\Sigma M_C = -T(5m) - T \frac{3}{\sqrt{34}}(10m) + W(5m) = 0$$
2. Sum forces in vertical direction to solve for the vertical reaction at point C, (Cy)
   $$\Sigma F_y = T + T\frac{3}{\sqrt{34}} - W + C_y = 0$$
3. Sum forces in the horizontal direction to solve for the horizontal reaction at point C, (Cx)
   $$\Sigma F_x = T\frac{5}{\sqrt{34}} - Cx = 0$$

Note that I just assumed directions for Cx and Cy in the sketch. If the equilibrium equations produce a negative value for either Cx or Cy it simply means the force acts in the opposite direction to the one I assumed.